# searching a string and printing the complete line containing that string

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I am trying to find out a MAC address in radius.log in the remote server with a small script in python. I want to search for one specific mac and print the complete line which contains that mac address. I can only do confirm the mac is found by search().

a part of my code is :

```
prog=re.compile(self.MAC_ADDR)
sess.exec_command('tail -f /usr/local/var/log/radius/radius.log')
rl, wl, xl = select.select([sess],[],[],0.0)
if len(rl) > 0:   #stdout
    block= sess.recv(1024)
    macfound=prog.search(block)
    if macfound:
        print "##############################################################################"
        print  self.MAC_ADDR,"found in tail"
        time.sleep (1)
```

Comment: Sorry, but what is your problem? You say you can confirm you actually find the MAC address, so your program seems to be working.

Comment: yes, no problem with the program however what i actually desire is to print the complete line which contains the mac. there are a bunch of lines in each block and current programme only confirms the mac exists in the block. i want to see the line printed as well.

Comment: You should show your regular expression (`self.MAC_ADDR`). If you use groups, you can capture the corresponding line in a regex group and print that group.

Comment: oh sorry, self.MAC_ADDR is just a single string val retrieved from a tkinter entry field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only using strings could be faster:

```
for line in all_blocks.splitlines():
    if MAC in line:
         print(line)
```

This gives you all the lines that the mac address is in, using regular expresssions:

```
prog = re.compile('^.*' + re.escape(MAC) + '.*$', re.MULTILINE)
lines = prog.findall(all_blocks)
```

Comment: First solution won't find the same `MAC` with different case. With `regex` it's easier to handle this issue. In second approach, why do you escape it? A MAC has no meta-character.

Comment: Nothing. I think it works as is. It's the OP who should say if it fits his needs.

Comment: did not understand how it works but second approach works perfectly for my condition. thank you